# Inferencing from tflite model in Java

Tags: java, tensorflow

I have exported a `tflite` model and using Python code on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api?fbclid=IwAR1ie4Fq6dvKbCocYCQ2WG_l9x2XSs1Nr0_2ECyXhmrGC_TZUNOMOLrS0po#using_the_interpreter_from_model_data_) link, I am able to do inferencing from this model. However, now I am trying to do inferencing in Android app using Java. I have been following official documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference?fbclid=IwAR2xUVdNSQpH2nMxQu020nw_QaXAB6owDaFM_1jpLVQI61SA-l1jYOzAtE0#java_2) but I am unable to get it work. Can someone guide me how to get it done? All I need is following steps.

1. Read `tflite` model.
2. Generate dummy record of shape [1,200,3]
3. Get inference from `tflite` model and print it.

I have been reading tflite demos but still could not get around it. To load model, I use

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(file_of_a_tensorflowlite_model)
```

from official document and get following error:

```
error: no suitable constructor found for Interpreter(String)
constructor Interpreter.Interpreter(File) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to File)
```

I am unable to resolve it. How do I do this simple task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste the TFLite model in your assets folder of your app. And then, use this code to load its `MappedByteBuffer`.

```
private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
        String MODEL_ASSETS_PATH = "recog_model.tflite";
        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(MODEL_ASSETS_PATH) ;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor() ) ;
        FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel() ;
        long startoffset = assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset() ;
        long declaredLength = assetFileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength() ;
        return fileChannel.map( FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY , startoffset , declaredLength ) ;
}
```

And then call it in the constructor.

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter( loadModelFile() )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found the problem and posted the answer. However, your answer is more elaborate so I will accept it. :)

Comment: where does the 'context' symbol come from??

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. The problem is, `new Interpreter(file_of_a_tensorflowlite_model)` does not take string file name as input. You have to make it a `MappedByteBuffer` and pass that to `Interpreter`.

```
new Interpreter(my_byte_buffer_method(abc.tflite))
```

After which it works fine. Just posting if someone else is facing the same issue.